# Doubts about Angular 5 routes

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, angular-router

I am new to Angular 5 development and I have doubts about routing in Angular 5.

I have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.ts. Here I load the login system of my page, after the login, I have a dashboard view with some links. I would like to keep up the navigation menu and load the content below the menu, but if I add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to the dashboard component, and click in a link, the page changes the component and it loses the menu.

How could I implenent a good routing system?

Comment: What does your routing declaration looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

For can use a differents router-outlet you can use children property in a route configuration.

If you have a dashboard you must create a module named dashboard and a component named also dashboard and other route module for dashboard module.

- dashboard.module.ts
- dashboard-routing.module.ts
- dashboard.component.ts
- dashboard.component.html

Dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
const routes : Routes = [
   {
     path : '', component: DashboardComponent,
     children : [
        {path: 'path', component: Component },
        .....
     ]
   }
]
```

Dashboard.component.html

Then, the routes within of DashboardComponent will be load within router-outlet of dashboard.component.html and here you can have a menu a static content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your navbar into a component itself.

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component        } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';

@Component
({
    selector    : 'navbar',
    templateUrl : './navbar.component.html'
})
```

navbar.component.html (your navbar html goes here)

```
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="route1" >Route1      </a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="route2" >Route2      </a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="route3" >Route3      </a></li>  
   </ul>
```

then embed the navbar component above the router outlet:

```
<navbar></navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have an angular 5 seed project here:

https://github.com/oneinazillion/landing-page